# How to print first least repeating character in a string

Tags: java, string, character, repeat

I want to print first least repeating character in String.
Input: zaazbbb
Output: z

In the above input z and a are repeating twice. they are least repeating characters and z is repeating first, so i want to get z as an output.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
class PrintLeastRepeatingCharacters
{
public static Character[] test(String s) 
    {
            Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
                char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
            for (Character c : ch) 
            {
                    if (map.containsKey(c)) 
                        {
                            map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            map.put(c, 1);
                    }
            }
            int minValue = Collections.min(map.values());
            List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) 
                {
                    if (entry.getValue().equals(minValue)) 
                    {
                            list.add(entry.getKey());
                    }
            }
            return list.toArray(new Character[0]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            String s = "zaazbb";
            Character[] arr = test(s);    
            System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "zaazbb";
         
        String arrayWithDuplicates[] = s.split("");  
  
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> hashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();   
          
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayWithDuplicates.length; j++) {   
            hashmap.put(arrayWithDuplicates[j], String.valueOf(j));   
        }   
        // use hashmap.keySet() for printing all keys of hashmap using it's keySet() method   
        for(String i:hashmap.keySet()){
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

please check if the above code works.. modified from https://www.javatpoint.com/find-unique-elements-in-array-java